# nx monorepo. Jest testing with msw. Error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in setupServer import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, msw, nx-monorepo

I use nx monorepo with react and try setup jest testing with msw (according to documentation https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#example-app-code)

Run test `nx test my-app` and get error below.
All other tests without msw work correct

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

/frontend/node_modules/msw/lib/node/index.d.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { PartialDeep } from 'type-fest';

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0TZb.png)

jest.config.ts

```
export default {
 displayName: 'my-app',
 preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
 transform: {
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)': '@nrwl/react/plugins/jest',
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['@nrwl/react/babel'] }],
 },
 moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/svg.js',
  },
 setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts"],
 moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
 coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/my-app',
 setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom'],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@nrwl/react/babel",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "pure": true, "ssr": true }]],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

devdependencies in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@inrupt/jest-jsdom-polyfills": "^2.5.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.4.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.7",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^1.1.0",
    "msw": "^2.0.8",
    "nx": "14.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.8.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json make sure you have the line `"type": "module"`

```
{
  "name": "Some Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

Comment: in this case get error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file apps/my-app/jest.config.ts

 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /jest.config.ts
   require() of ES modules is not supported.
   require() of /jest.config.ts from /node_modules/@nrwl/jest/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js is an ES module file as it is a .ts file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .ts files in that package scope as ES modules.
 Instead change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /package.json